# Image Filtering for noisy galaxy images and the efficiency

Tags: python, image-processing, astronomy

I'm new to image processing, I have filtered galaxy images using median filtering(using open cv),and the impact isn't that great.To measure the effectiveness of the filter,I tried PSNR,but it seems to be the wrong metrics,while comparing the noisy and de-noised images.

#### Image before filtering

[image: Image before filtering]

#### Image after filtering

[image: Image after filtering]

Should I use bilateral or non-local means filtering for de-noising?And what is the correct metrics to evaluate the performance.Many research papers mentions SSIM as well.Should using that be useful for a noisy and de-noised image?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65537552/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

There are many sources of noise and each has different methods of cleaning. See [this guide](https://www.eso.org/%7Eohainaut/ccd/) for the basic steps of image processing in astronomy.

These steps depend greatly on what you have at your disposal. If you just have a single image of each galaxy, the only thing you can do is background subtraction (by taking an average of the darkest area of the image, and then subtracting that value from the whole image).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)